# Difficulty with checkbox hack syntax

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to both style a label and reveal a div when a checkbox is checked. I have found ways to do one or the other, but not both, and I don't understand why. Note the CSS is the exact same in both examples and is:

```
input {
  display: none
}

.layerpic {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
}

label {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
}

.xyz input:checked + .layerpic{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.xyz input:checked + label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now the HTML. This example allows the div to be affected, but not the label. Note the only difference is in the html where the label comes before the input:

```
<div class ="xyz">
  <label class="ribs" for="hider2">Hide layer</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hider2">
  <div class="layerpic"> hi
  </div>
</div>
```

This example allows the label to be affected, but not the div:

```
<div class ="xyz">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hider2">
  <label class="ribs" for="hider2">Hide layer</label>
  <div class="layerpic"> hi
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain why different elements are affected just by flipping which HTML comes first, and is it possible to have both elements affected when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors check out how the '+' operator works in css. should clear things up.

Comment: This makes so much sense now. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearrange your HTML, then use **[`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)**  and **[`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)** selectors

```css
input {
  display: none
}

.layerpic {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
}

label {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
}

.xyz input:checked+.layerpic {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.xyz input:checked~label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hider2">
  <div class="layerpic"> hi</div>
  <label class="ribs" for="hider2">Hide layer</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Very much appreciated.